# How to localize bundle display name in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, localization, bundle

How can I localize bundle display name of an iPhone app?
The name displayed in iPhone main screen under app icon.
I wish a single binary bundle package which will be displayed multilingually.

Comment: Currently the procedures are described in this official document:  https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html

Answer (score 49):

Here's some instructions:

- Create a new empty file called `InfoPlist.strings`
- Open up the Navigator (`cmd-opt-0`) and select the first pane
- Click the plus for a localization
- Xcode (4.3) goes a bit funny and deselects your file. It's placed it into a localization folder (probably called `en.lproj` in the item's original folder. Re-select it in the Project Navigator.
- Your file now has (probably) English in the Localization list. Click the plus button to add another language.

It's generally good to start with all the items you want to localize in the same folder, that way when they get localized, Xcode doesn't create a whole bunch of `en.lproj` and `ja.lproj` files all over your project. Call it something like "Localized Resources".

You can localize the app name now by adding the localized name to each file like this (for the French localized file):

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "Bonjour";
```

[image: Localize]
[image: Localize Two]

Answer (score 47):

Okay, even though this is a pretty old question, it came up high on my google searches for this topic. Hence I thought it might make sense to update the answers:

In Xcode 4.X, follow these steps to localize your bundle name:

1. File->New->File...
2. Choose Resource->Strings File
3. Type in the Filename as InfoPlist.strings and save it in the correct location. **EVEN If your plist is named App-Info.plist - the filename is ALWAYS InfoPlist.strings!**
4. Now the file should be open (otherwise, select it). In the left drawer, select "Localize"
   [image] and after confirming that the newly created file is moved to the English folder, check the other languages you want. For a language to show up here, it needs to be listed as your localization languages
5. Add these two lines to the InfoPlist.strings for the correct language:

   "CFBundleDisplayName" = "Name";

   "CFBundleName" = "Name";
6. Add a new line to your App-Info.plist, "Localization native Development Region" - this set's the default development region

And after "only" 6 simple steps, you can set your localized app name!!11!1111

Answer (score 10):

Xcode 9.4.1

Create a new file called InfoPlist.string (string file)

Add your languages to this file, in the Localization-menu on the right, after clicking once on the new file. Expand the InfoPlist.sting file and add CFBundleDisplayName in all files with your translations:

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "My i18n App Name";
```

In Info.plist add two new values(or make sure they are there):

```
Bundle display name = $(PRODUCT_NAME)
Application has localized display name = YES
```

Answer (score 6):

Add  InfoPlist.strings to your project and localize it. Put this in different languages:

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "App Name";
```

Comment: This was the only thing I needed with a new iOS project using Xcode 14. For macos I also needed to add the LSHasLocalizedDisplayName key https://stackoverflow.com/a/73776924/827047

Answer (score 2):

In Info.plist provide the localized (translated) name for the following keys:

```
Bundle Display Name
Bundle Name
```

This will show up your application translated name under the icon on iPhone desktop

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Xcode 13 2022**

First add any localisations you need in the project info

[image]

Then similar to all the older answers,

1. create a new strings file called InfoPlist
2. Tick all the localisations you added in the right bar
3. use the breadcrumb nav to update the CFBundleDisplayName prop per locale

[image: Xcode translated infoplist]

Comment: I don't understand step 1: `create a new strings file called InfoPlist` where do we do this? Where do we create it and in which folder?

Comment: Sorry for the late response @mesqueeb go to file > create new file> strings file

Answer (score 0):

This is how to localize app name in **Xcode 15** using **String Catalog**.

1. To localize the app name, we need to do something else. Now create a new **String Catalog** file called `InfoPlist`
2. Add Localized String Values for `CFBundleDisplayName` and `CFBundleName` to both your base language and your other translations.
3. Build and verify the changes.

[image]

See more detailed steps at https://imgracehuang.medium.com/how-to-localize-the-app-name-in-xcode-15-using-string-catalog-95b7734a3a38