# How to localize the app name?

Tags: ios, iphone, localization, cocos2d-iphone

I wrote a game with cocos2d and translated all the image and text in the
game in two different language.

When the app launches, I load different resource according to the locale of 
the device and this worked all OK.

Then when I upload this app for review, I first named it say "test".
Then in the localization part I add a language "Japanese".

But I found that in the "Japanese meta data part", I can edit a lot of
things except the "app name" which is "test". But I want my app to show
different names according to the locale of the device also.

Can somebody tell me how to get this work? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to localize bundle display name in iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871990/how-to-localize-bundle-display-name-in-iphone-app)

Answer (score 5):

You can create a file called `InfoPlist.strings` in each of your language specific directories, and set a language specific value for **CFBundleDisplayName**.

Comment: Where is "each of your language specific directories" ? Can you give some example paths?