# Xcode: Application name in OS X cannot be localized?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, localization

I have an project named "Multi-Camera Supervisor". I make the "MainMenu.xib" file localized. Here are the menu bar in localized nib file of Xcode:

Xib file for English:
[image]

Xib file for Japanese:
[image]

---

But when I ran my application in Xcode, The first item doesn't work. Here are the menu bars when my application ran:

Running menu bar for English:
[image]

Running menu bar for Japanese
[image]

---

You can see that the application name was still "Multi-Camera Supervisor" and NOT LOCALIZED.
Meanwhile, the application name appeared in Dock icon was not localized either.
How should I solve this? How can I localize the application name not only in main menu but also in Dock?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you add a `LSHasLocalizedDisplayName` key with a boolean value of `YES` to the app's `Info.plist`. I believe that key is necessary to make sure the localized `CFBundleDisplayName` and `CFBundleName` values are used for the menu.

Comment: Ah, "CFBundleName" is exactly what I need! thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The App name in the menu bar is set in the nib file, traditionally called "MainMenu.xib". You can set the name like any other menu name in that file by clicking on it in the Interface Builder tab of Xcode.

For the display in the Finder, just set the `CFBundleDisplayName` in the Info.plist file.

You can read more about it in the [Info.plist reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-SW1).

There are many useful keys in that file to customise the appearance and launch of your apps.

Comment: I have done this. But I found that `CFBundleDisplayName` only takes effect in the Finder, but not in menu bar...

Comment: I tried log out OS X and re-login. This time, The application name in Dock was localized successfully. But the first menu item `"Multi-Camera Supervisor"` remained in English.

Comment: True - sorry, that is localised in the nib file. There may be some way to do it programmatically, too, but I am not aware of it. Will amend the answer.