# Localization of app icon is not working iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, localization

I am trying to localize my `App Icon, App name, and Launch Screen.` `I can localize my App Name and Launch Screen, but I am not able to localize the app icon`. Is there any way to localize App Icon. I can see that apple has localized their app icons in different languages...

[image]

Comment: just follow these 6 steps -->   http://stackoverflow.com/a/13510919/4970453

Comment: @Varinder Singh, I localized my App name. want to localize app icon also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [tutorial](http://db42.in/2015/02/15/locale-based-ios-app-branding/) might be helpful.

Though the articles I had read says from iOS 4.0 Apple has stopped providing support to localize app icons. They would just say create different app icons for different markets.

Since the apps that you are showing are apple's itself. They have the privilege to it.