# How to use user defined settings in infoplist.strings file?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've defined **BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME -> XXX** as a user defined settings in my target's build settings. Now in my info.plist file I've used it as **Bundle display name -> ${BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME}**. And in my InfoPlist.strings file I've used **"CFBundleDisplayName" = "${BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME}"**.

Now the problem is when I run my app, app name appears as **${BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME}** instead of **XXX**. But if I remove InfoPlist.strings declaration it works fine and displays correct name i.e. **XXX**. So there is a problem the way I declare it in InfoPlist.strings but I don't know what?.

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to localize a Build Setting, which can't be done. If you want to use a **User-Defined Build Setting** as your `CFBundleDisplayName`, then it's going to be a static string. Build Setting variables (e.g. `$(PRODUCT_NAME)`) won't be replaced in `InfoPlist.strings` (or any `.strings` file for that matter).

Comment: If you want to localize your app's display name, that is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871990/how-to-localize-bundle-display-name-in-iphone-app

Answer (score -1):

There is no predefined key with ${BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME}, you should use $(PRODUCT_NAME) in Info.plist to get the correct name.

Comment: BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME is user defined attribute in app's build settings.

Comment: What you want to achieve by doing this ?