# xcode preview could not be built into project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

canvas preview has an error just like that:

> UnknownPreviewProviderError: Unknown preview provider
>   "AboutView_Previews" 买就返.app does not contain a preview provider named
>   "AboutView_Previews".  Check your build settings to ensure the preview
>   provider is compiled into your product. Mangled name:
>   3买就返18AboutView_PreviewsV
>
> Error Domain=com.apple.dt.UITestingAgent Code=-1 "Preview provider
>   "3买就返18AboutView_PreviewsV" does not exist" 
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Preview provider
>   "3买就返18AboutView_PreviewsV" does not exist}

ihave check the "build setting" -> "build options" -> "Enable Previews" is Yes

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            HomeView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image("tabbarHome")
                    Text("首页")
            }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like Xcode issue due to 买就返 application name. You can use English product name and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871990/how-to-localize-bundle-display-name-in-iphone-app) topic of how to make app name localized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**just 
`change App name ("Buy back")`
it will solve your issue**

Comment: Please elaborate on why your answer will solve the problem.

Comment: because by default localization is not support you need to provide localization of your name to Chineeze and after you can do that

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue when I modify the Product Name(at Target -> Packing -> Product Name) to Chinese word.

The right way to use Chinese word as App name:

1. open info.plist
2. add Bundle display name with the name you want.

Use this way to change app name will not effect SwiftUI Previews.

Answer (score 1):

There was a similar error when the project name started with a digit (for example, 30-project-name). I just **renamed** the project with a name without numbers at the beginning